# R: How do I match a column paired with a letter with another column paired with an empty column to fill in the empty column

Tags: r

I'm working in a dataframe that looks like

```
Word.  letter   Word2.  letter2

happy.  p.      SAD
sad.    n.      POTATO
potato  o.      HAPPY
```

I want it to look like this

```
Word.  letter   Word2.  letter2

happy.  p.      SAD.     n
sad.    n.      POTATO.  o
potato  o.      HAPPY.   p
```

Basically I want to make it so that I can identify "word" in "word2" and copy the "letter" and place it accordingly in "letter2". I need to make sure it matches regardless if case.

I have tried to use the match function in a variety of different manners but I am either making stupid syntax errors, it isn't matching case, or both. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

**Data Visualization**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Word = c("happy", "sad", "potato"), letter = c("p", 
"n", "o"), Word2 = c("SAD", "POTATO", "HAPPY"), letter2 = c("n", "o", "p")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

One of my attempts:

```
df1<-(mydataframe)
df1$letter2<-with(df1, letter2[match(letter, letter2)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to upper case and do a match

```
df1$letter2 <- with(df1, letter[match(Word2, toupper(Word))])
df1$letter2
#[1] "n" "o" "p"
```